# mysqlshow with grep for a row at a time

Tags: mysql, bash, grep

i want to download all databases of a cpanels users but i want seperate databases not --all-databases, so, i thought to create a `bash script` with a loop to `grep` a line at a time database and download the databases, go to next line

from ssh something near this is

```
mysqlshow | grep -n  openworl | head -n 1
```

(openworl is the name of cpanel user that belong that database)

this will brink me the first entry of mysqlshow of that user, how can i change this command in my loop so the next run will give me the second, third ,etc row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can use a for loop :

```
for line in "$(mysqlshow |grep -n openworl)";do
     echo $line
     do stuff ...
done
```

This will enumerate through every item generated by your command `mysqlshow |grep -n openworl` and store the temporary results in `$line`

Comment: i did it, i coudn't do it instantly cause of time limit , thx a lot